# Magento 2.3 What are the profits of using db_schema.xml instead of using setup script?

Tags: magento2.3, setup-script, magento2.3.1, declarative-schema

Magento 2.3 used db_schema.xml instead of setup script. What are the benefits of using db_schema.xml over setup script?

Answer (score 2):

According to devdocs:

> When a customer upgrades Magento to a version several releases ahead
>   of the installed version, the upgrade script for each intermediate
>   release still executes. Developers were required to fully understand
>   what each install and upgrade script contained. They needed to account
>   for this complexity when creating extensions.
>
> The new declarative schema approach allows developers to declare the
>   final desired state of the database and has the system adjust to it
>   automatically, without performing redundant operations. Developers are
>   no longer forced to write scripts for each new version. In addition,
>   this approach allows data be deleted when a module is uninstalled.

[More detail](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/)

Answer (score 0):

Please Can you read the developer doc of magento. there is a very peaceful description about **db_schema.xml**

for more information please read this one [db_schema](https://cedcommerce.com/blog/declarative-schema-in-magento-2-3/)